# 403 Forbidden error shows only in one page

Tags: php, codeigniter, networking, router, http-status-code-403

I used PHP (Codeigniter) in a project. I have uploaded it into a web server. One of my clients, keep complaining about a 403 Forbidden error on a specific page. I have tested that page with **other networks** it's working fine, but only this client can't view that specific page. He could login and see other pages.
Client told me he could load the that page with a mobile network.

1. What is the cause of this problem?
2. Which caused the problem, client's network or the PHP Project?
3. Is it because router's DNS caching?

Please provide some solutions to fix this problem. Thanks a lot!

This is the exact error message:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access "Path to file" on this server.
Additionally, a 403 error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache 2.222 (Unix) mod_ssl 2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.02.2635 mod perl/2.0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /folderName/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

web servers provide more specific information about the cause of 403 Forbidden errors by suffixing a number after the 403 as in HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden which means Directory listing denied.